# Worksheet change

Tags: excel, vba

Morning all!
I'm trying to create a code using the worksheet change that when a cell with a function is activate, another cell.

Like this:

```
If Target.Column = 10 And Target.Value <> "" Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
Target.Offset(0, 1) = Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm")
Application.EnableEvents = True
End if
```

Of course that doens't work because the cell with the function doesn't have value null.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "a cell with a function is activate"? Does the cell have a specific formula?

Comment: Exaclty, it has a formula.

Comment: `Target.HasFormula` instead of `Target.Value <> ""`?

Comment: worksheet_change isn't triggered by a formula recalculation

Comment: @BigBen, thanks for your help!

Using `Target.HasFormula`, the cell on column 11 it's filled with the time I fill the column 10 with a formula.

I'm trying to: column 9 has a drop-drown list, column 10 change to "ok" ("if" formula) when I select a name from column 9. I'm trying to make column 11 give me the time that action occurred.

EDIT: @TimWilliams any idea how I can solve that problem?

Comment: Use `Worksheet_Calculate` instead of `Worksheet_Change`. Sorry, I misunderstood what you were trying to do.